# video file broadcast in website

Tags: broadcasting

I want to broadcast a video file on my website like it will broadcast at 9pm . it is 10 minute's video and when someone open my website at  9:05pm then video will start after 5 minutes because it is already played 5 minutes and 5 minutes still remaining. when some one open website at 9:12pm then nothing will play because video already played from 9:00pm to 9:10pm

Comment: so you need some advice on how to do this or you already have the application but facing some problem with it ?

Comment: Yes  I need help . How to do this.